# How to find records with mismatched times

Tags: mysql

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to find records in a MySQL database that only pull out dates/times that don't match?

Sample Data

```
MainTicket           ChildTicket          Start time        End Time
77777                5414550              3/9/18 19:30      3/10/18 1:00
77777                5551415              3/9/18 10:28      3/10/18 1:00
```

We have one main ticket here with two child tickets.  The start times do not match and I need to have a SQL report that only pulls data like this.

```
MainTicket              ChildTicket          StartTime         End time
5555555                 4564565              3/2/18 21:00      3/4/18 14:00
5555555                 1561610              3/2/18 21:00      3/4/18 14:00
```

Here the dates and times do match, so I don't want to see those.

Comment: the expected output data can not be found with in the sample data..for answers you should provide better sample data with matching expected output.

Comment: Not sure what you mean Raymond?  The data I need the query to pull is any "MainTicket" that has a "Start Time" that does NOT match

Comment: so out of the four rows of sample data, the expected output should be 

77777